# How can I fix launch time performance and suspend performance in WACK report?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-runtime, app-certification-kit

I tested my app with WACK and I got the following result. How can I solve these two warnings, and can I put my app in the AppStore?

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Overall Score: PASSED WITH WARNINGS

Launch time performance

WARNING
Performance Launch
Warning: Following results were encountered while running the Performance Launch test.
Application App has a launch time of 0.971 secs.
Application App has CPU utilization of 12.15 percent. CPU utilization of 50 percent or higher can significantly degrade performance for Application Launch/Suspend.
Application App allocates process private memory of 0 MB. Process private memory usage of greater than 25 MB can significantly degrade performance for Application Launch/Suspend.
Application App issues File I/O of 0.722 MB. Issuing File I/O of 50 MB or higher can significantly degrade performance for Application Launch/Suspend.
Impact if not fixed: Application launch is your customer’s first experience and impression of your Metro style application. To ensure system responsiveness applications are expected to launch within 5 seconds. Windows 8 is targeted at a broad range of hardware configurations and this launch time target is intended to provide a good baseline of performance across the broadest range of hardware capabilities. It is important to understand the launch performance of your application, while taking hardware capabilities into consideration. If your application has passed this test locally but has launch times which are close to the required limits, consider what type of hardware this test is being executed on as your application could potentially fail the Windows Store certification process. Reducing resource utilization can reduce the duration of launch, especially when contention for resources is high.
How to fix: Additional information can be found here.


Suspend performance

WARNING
Performance Suspend
Warning: Following results were encountered while running the Performance Suspend test.
Application App has a suspend time of 0.005 secs.
Application App has CPU utilization of 9.11 percent. CPU utilization of 50 percent or higher can significantly degrade performance for Application Launch/Suspend.
Application App issues File I/O of 0 MB. Issuing File I/O of 20 MB or higher can significantly degrade performance for Application Launch/Suspend.
Impact if not fixed: In the Metro style user experience, Application suspend is a very frequent occurrence. To ensure fast and fluid multitasking, applications are expected to suspend within 2 seconds. Windows 8 is targeted at a broad range of hardware configurations and this suspend time target is intended to provide a good baseline of performance across the broadest range of hardware capabilities. It is important to understand the suspend performance of your application, while taking hardware capabilities into consideration. If your application has passed this test locally but has suspend times which are close to the required limits, consider what type of hardware this test is being executed on as your application could potentially fail the Windows Store certification process. Reducing resource utilization during can improve the duration of suspend, especially when contention for resources is high.
How to fix: Additional information can be found here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every app gets those warnings in Consumer Preview, as they are used to report the startup and suspend times. You'll see that your numbers are well below the threshold of concern. These warnings won't cause a problem with the Store--every app you see in the Store today got those warnings too.